# Oauth problems with Scribe

Tags: java, oauth, scribe

I'm using scribe for making an app that has oauth support. I didn't found problems With Twitter, but when using facebook I have problems...

This is the code that works on twitter oauth

```
OAuthService s = /* ... Facebook oauth init ... */
final Token requestToken = s.getRequestToken();
final String authURL = s.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
```

It gives me an error at the second line:

```
12-20 10:01:31.475: E/AndroidRuntime(5405): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported operation, please use 'getAuthorizationUrl' and redirect your users there
12-20 10:01:31.475: E/AndroidRuntime(5405):     at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth20ServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth20ServiceImpl.java:45)
```

I know that it says that I might use getAuthorizationUrl... But I have to pass a requestToken...

Could you please help me?

It would be helpful any example with Scribe and Facebook

Thanks!

PS: Same problem with Windows Live ! =(

EDIT:

I have been looking at the source code of the Scribe library and I found something

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/oauth/OAuth20ServiceImpl.java

Here we can see that I can call the getAuthorizationUrl(...) with null parameter because it doesn't use it.... But I think the prioblem now is that the config isn't filled...

here is how I initialize facebook service:

```
new ServiceBuilder()
    .provider(FacebookApi.class)
    .apiKey(....)
    .apiSecret(....)
    .scope("email,offline_access")
    .callback("oauth://facebook")
    .build();
```

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Facebook uses OAuth version 2, Twitter uses OAuth 1. Do you know the difference?

Comment: I know it... and i thought it was the problem... but I don't know really well the differences...

Comment: You've got the 2 protocols wrong, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private static final Token EMPTY_TOKEN = null;

OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                           .provider(FacebookApi.class)
                            .apiKey(apiKey)
                            .apiSecret(apiSecret)
                             .callback("http://www.example.com/oauth_callback/")
                              .build();
 String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(EMPTY_TOKEN);
```

All you now need to redirect user to this URL and let him verify them self to get code from facebok.

There are a good amount of example with very good documentation for almost all major Oath
system

here is for Facebook

[FacebookExample](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/blob/master/scribejava-apis/src/test/java/com/github/scribejava/apis/examples/FacebookExample.java)

For all major providers
[Scribe Example Directory](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/tree/master/scribejava-apis/src/test/java/com/github/scribejava/apis/examples)

**Edit**

After looking at the discussion my suggestion is to get a full understanding about Oauth1 and Oauth2.

Comment: Arguably this is a small blunder on the part of Scribe; it should simply return null from an OAuth 2 implementation of `getRequestToken`.

Answer (score 7):

You've got it all wrong. OAuth 2 Protocol never returns a request token like OAuth 1.

Oauth 1 does an HTTP POST request and returns an unauthorized request token. Then, you will have to authorize your unauthorized token to receive an authorized token (That's 2 HTTP call).

Oauth 2, on the other hand, doesn't have a request token flow, you will need to do an HTTP GET for an *authorization token* (1 HTTP call only). Hence why Scribe says that you need to call `getAuthorizedUrl`.

See this [Facebook Example](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/FacebookExample.java), to see how to retrieve an authorized token using OAuth 2.